# How handle long operation with UI report on RCP close?

Tags: java, eclipse, jobs, eclipse-rcp, rcp

When closing my Eclipse (for plugin development) workbench while a long operation is running in my workbench (and thus reported to me through the progress view) such as a "Clean all" action the following happen:

1. the main workbench window is closed
2. a new small window (a dialog I guess) is opened with the same content than the previous progress view. This dialog informs me that some operations are being completed before actually closing the application

How can I achieve the same behavior in an RCP application with my own Jobs running long operations ?

Thansk for your help,
Manu

Comment: I think doing your work in a UIJob could implement it like eclipse itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about looking in the eclipse-IDE code to see how its implemented ;)
Small advice:

```
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postShutdown()
```

in bundle

```
org.eclipse.ui.ide.application
```